# How can I modify a String in a class file which is in a compiled .jar with a Java Program?

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a Client-builder, which means I have a client.jar and I need to change a `String` which is located in `jar/client/Main.class`. The String IP_SERVER = (value I want to change) is the only thing which should be edited. May there is a way to replace the class with a by java builded and compiled class, but idk.The Client Builder is a Java Program with Gui (but gui isnt the problem) wich is used to create copies of the original Client.jar just with changed values (Ip String for example). I need this and not arguments or something cause the client.jar should be able to be given to other people when they DONT know the Server Ip. So things like start arguments or something arent so usefull :/

I already tried to copy Files into the Jar, but that is not really what I need. So how can I do this with a Java Program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the motives are questionable, there are ways to modify the bytecode. The jar file is a glorified zip file wich  you have to decompress. Then you have to edit the class file. If you don't change the size of the strings (or other structures) inside, you can get away with simple find/replace.

If you want to do more extensive modifications, there are libraries to modify the class bytecode. And the ultimate approach would be to:

1. Unzip the jar
2. Decompile the class file
3. Do text modification on the Java code
4. Recompile the modified Java code( probably have to bring the whole jdk with you)
5. Replace the class file
6. Zip to a new jar
7. Replace the old jar

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the answer is: then don't make that string "code only".

Instead, make it **configurable** from the outside, for example by checking
- is there a JVM property that tells you a different IP address
- is there an environment variable that tells you a different IP address

Don't waste your time looking for a dirty workaround by somehow manipulating compiled class files. Instead: write code that can be easily configured where needed, without touching source code (or worse, compiled artefacts).

And given your comment: JAR files can contain **resources**, like: a property file. Yes, you can have a text property file coming *inside* your JAR file, that gets read at runtime. So yes, theoretically you could "bake" such information *into* your JAR. But again, that would be rather bad practice. A JAR is a binary file, and would you really want that two customers that are on the same *version* of your tool ... would be using two different JAR files?! Again: this is configuration information, and configuration should exist **outside** of your JAR.

Finally: your requirements are contradicting each other. Either you want to generate a SINGLE jar file ... or not. If you want to deliver a single JAR file, then there is no way but taking that "other" JAR file, add your main method. And then it really doesn't matter where that string is coming from. But you can't expect to distribute the content of *another* JAR file ... without incorporating that, when you also intend to only hand out some extra JAR you created.

Answer (score 1):

To add a sort of combination between GhostCat's answer and Dr Phil's answer, you could have a text file that contains the server IP that is simply read by your Java class at class-initialization time. The text file would be a *resource* (i.e. it's bundled inside in your JAR file).

```
public class Main {

    public static final String IP_SERVER;

    static {
        try (InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("path/to/resource/file.txt")) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            IP_SERVER = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

The above code assumes your text file will have the IP information on the first line (and ignores any other lines). You will probably want to create the `InputStreamReader` with an explicit charset (the one used to encode your text file) rather than relying on the default charset (see the documentation of `InputStreamReader` for more details).

To modify the text file you could use a similar approach to that described in Dr Phil's answer. The only difference here is that you're modifying a text file which means you don't need to recompile any source files.

Instead of a text file, you could use a properties file (i.e. `*.properties`). You would then use the [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html) class to access it (again, as a *resource*).

Answer (score 0):

Include that file in your project with the original package. While compiling your class will be detected first instead of that client.jar. For this, in the compilation path, your class files should be in first instead of that client.jar.